# CMD Command Prompt DIR Batch File

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, cmd.exe

1. I use CMD to create a text file for a directory of directories (ie. 2014 Folder containing folders for each project that year).
2. Piping the DIR command to create a text file is very useful, but would love to automate the process as much as possible.
3. I import the text file into Excel to cull the data.
4. I am curious if there is a way to remove the Header and Footer (along with the folders named <.> and <..> b/c I'm not sure what they even are).
5. But would like to know if this is possible before the text file hits Excel.
6. I have come close with my current batch, but it leaves two blank rows at the top; which may not be a big deal, but I would like to know the best way possible.

*It seems this could be a very common situation, I just cannot find a specific batch w/o being to complex for my understanding.

**My current batch file uses this type of approach: DIR, REN (for whatever reason to modify the old file into a new one) and FINDSTR /V "Volume Directory .. bytes" dir01.txt.old > dir01.txt

```
TITLE Project Folders 
DIR S:\"Project Folder 2014\Projects" /T:C /O:-N > S:\MyFolder\dir01.txt 
DIR S:\"Project Folder 2014\Projects" /T:W /O:-N > S:\MyFolder\dir02.txt 
DIR S:\"Project Folder 2014\Projects" /T:A /O:-N > S:\MyFolder\dir03.txt 
S: 
CD MyFolder 
REN dir01.txt dir01.txt.old 
REN dir02.txt dir02.txt.old 
REN dir03.txt dir03.txt.old 
FINDSTR /V "Volume Directory .. bytes" dir01.txt.old > dir01.txt 
FINDSTR /V "Volume Directory .. bytes" dir02.txt.old > dir02.txt 
FINDSTR /V "Volume Directory .. bytes" dir03.txt.old > dir03.txt 
DEL dir01.txt.old dir02.txt.old dir03.txt.old 
PAUSE
```

***Please advise!

The bare format will not be useful; as I use the date created, modified, and accessed in 3 separate text files to use for tracking the projects

Would this be easier to accomplish in PowerShell?

Comment: Please show us your batch file, and do clarify what you really are after with this. Giving some kind of a example of the files and subfolders would also make it easier to answer.

Comment: CMD is not very nice to do complex things with, so if you know PowerShell it might be easier to get good results with it.

Comment: Yeah, I figured. I just learned about CMD before PowerShell; so it's what I feel more comfortable with at the time and it seems more simple.

Comment: I copied the code to the question body where it is easier to format things. (the edit might not be visible immediately due to moderating)

Comment: [Why do you ask the same question?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32655352/3439404)

Comment: Yes, please don't cross-post to multiple SE sites.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 - Yes, what? I just realized this was part of the same site (why? I'm not sure) Thanks for the input. Also, this is something I currently need help with, not a post for 2 years ago. It seems you do not have an answer to something that should have been answered in 1990.

Answer (score 1):

I used `findstr /R "^[0-12]"` as per [Marc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32655478/55075) answer at [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32655352/55075), so I guess b/c the date(month) is the start of each line I need; minus the two folders named [.] and [..]. But this will suffice. Thanks again!